# Common configuration files for Windows Forms applications

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am newbie in [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms). I have a few configuration files which are used for multiple purposes in the application. I want to have those files stored in the common `appdata` folder when the Windows application is installed, which can be accessed using this path:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

What is the best way of achieving so as it requires minimal user attention?

P.S: Currently files are stored in the application's installation directory, hence a user with lesser administrator rights has problems hence the change in strategy.

Comment: probably rephrase it, that user does not have to copy the file to appdata and should be done during app startup (i am guessing this).

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but it should work.

When you run this, you'll want to first verify that the paths in `sourceFolder` and `targetFolder` point to the correct location.

```
var sourceFolder = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
var targetFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

Then you can enumerate over the files that match a particular pattern (here I assumed your settings files end in `.ini`, but you can change the pattern as needed), and move each of them to the new location.

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder);
foreach (var file in di.EnumerateFiles("*.ini"))
    File.Move(file.FullName, Path.Combine(targetFolder, file.Name));
```